# Applying multiple CSS classes from different sources (module and non)

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have found many articles and solutions on adding multiple css classes to a React div.

However I can't find anything explaining how to apply multiple classes when one class comes from a module and the other doesn't.

My js component imports two stylesheets.

```
import styles from "./text-image-section.module.scss";
import "../../animate.scss";
```

I am trying to apply both classes to a div

```
<div className={`${styles.textContainer} .animate`}>
```

Comment: Remove the dot: `className={\`${styles.textContainer} animate\`}`

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a module's class, string interpolation is usable, as you're importing it into a variable `styles` (as opposed to a plain string).

However, when access a non-module class, you can just put the name of the class down.
So, for your case, instead of putting
`` <div className={`${styles.textContainer} .animate`}>// content...</div> ``,

you can put
`` <div className={`${styles.textContainer} animate`}>// content...</div> ``

This is assuming "animate" is a class inside of `"../../animate.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You can import global classnames the same way you import scoped classnames.

```
import styles from "./text-image-section.module.scss";
import global from "../../animate.scss";

<div className={`${styles.textContainer} ${global.animate}`} />
```

resulting DOM

```html
<div class="__s323dhf123sa56f_textContainer animate"></div>
```